# Android: AsyncTask and Constructor

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I using the class async to download and upload data in two activitys. The upload is not working and I dunno why.

This one works fine!

```
        new DatabaseConnector(true).execute("http://web2page.ch/apps/FruityNumber/highscoreShow.php");
```

But this one not!

```
        new DatabaseConnector(false).execute("http://web2page.ch/apps/FruityNumber/highscoreUpload.php?user=test7&highscore=timer7");
```

But if I remove "if" in the class it works fine... Does someone understand why?

```
public DatabaseConnector(Boolean download) {
    this.download = download;
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        try {
            //Verbinden
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            if (download) {
                //Falls die App nochmal geladen wird, sind die Daten nur einmal enthalten. Darum leeren.
                arrayList.clear();

                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
                    arrayList.add(line);
                }
            } else {

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See comments in code

`new DatabaseConnector(false)` means

```
public DatabaseConnector(Boolean download) {
    this.download = false;  // see here
}
```

so

```
 if (download) { // this won't execute because download == false
```

and

```
else {
    // there is nothing here to do!
}
```

I'm not sure how you expect anything different..

To solve this will depend on why you are even using the `boolean` variable. If there is no reason for it then remove that and don't pass it anything.

Otherwise, it sounds like you want to put the upload code in the `else{}`

Comment: like that bor @Blackbelt?

Comment: definitely like that bor

Comment: @codeMagic :But it should at least do the first part... `           url = new URL(params[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();`

Comment: How do you know it doesn't? Have you checked the logs or set breakpoints to make sure you aren't getting an exception?

Comment: does he have the internet permission orb ?

Comment: Yes because if `download == true` then it runs properly bor @Blackbelt

Comment: I'm sure it doesnt work because I dont see any input on the Website.

Comment: You won't because you are doing anything to send input to the website! You are only trying to connect if it is false!

Comment: No I am not. The if comes after the connection.

Comment: I understand. And at what point are you sending data to the server?

Comment: I guess at httpURLConnection.connect();...? or not?

Comment: This URL http://web2page.ch/apps/FruityNumber/highscoreUpload.php?user=test7&highscore=timer7. There is a php file that get the user and highscore.

Comment: Set breakpoints or logs in your method to see what is/isn't called